# How to do SQL query for DISTINCT and COUNT at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct

I try to do a query which allow me to `DISTINCT column1 (name), column2 (mode) and column3 (date)`. But at the same time, I want to count the value in column `mode` from the same table. I try to join these 2 queries (**below**), but the queries are from the same table. Are there any solution ?

1. SELECT DISTINCT Name, Mode, Date FROM table_name
2. SELECT COUNT(Mode) FROM table_name

[image: Expected result]

The `OnHand` column is `COUNT` from the Mode column

Comment: Please provide sampe ata and eesired results.

Comment: I have included the expected result

Comment: . . Your result is not in the format of a table.  In a *table* all rows have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want window functions:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY column2) as column2_cnt
FROM table_name 2
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3;
```

On each row, you will have the count of `column2` values *over the entire table*.  So the values will be repeated on rows with the same `column2` value.

EDIT:

Based on your revised question, you seem to want:

```
SELECT name, mode, date,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) as cnt
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name, mode, date;
```

You can express this in other ways:

```
SELECT t.name, t.mode, t.date, tn.cnt
FROM table_name t JOIN
     (SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT mode, date) as cnt
      FROM table_name t
      GROUP BY name
     ) tn
     ON t.name = tn.name
GROUP BY t.name, t.mode, t.date, tn.cnt;
```

Comment: I have edited the question and included the expected result, can you please look at it ?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have tried your edited query. But there is an error at round bracket after OVER, saying that **"(" is not valid at this position, expecting: EOF, ';'**
This is the code I used `COUNT(mode) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS cnt

Comment: @Lilly . . . Window functions are available starting in MySQL 8+, so the edited query depends on your version of MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm using MySQL workbench 8.0, I think window function are available for my version. This is my query 
`SELECT name, mode, date
       COUNT(mode) OVER(PARTITION BY name) AS cnt
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name, mode, date;`